# How to remove the redundant adjacencies on a DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm to reduce the redundant adjacencies in a directed acyclic graph. I've made a bit of research and I've found some topics that reference the **transitive reduction**.

After some tests, I've concluded that **it isn't sufficient for me**. It seems that **the transitive reduction only remove the redundant dependencies in the first level:**

For example:

If there's an edge `a -> b` and an edge `b -> c` then **it removes the edge `a -> c`.** But if there's an edge `a -> b`, `b -> c`, and `c -> d`, then **it does not remove the edge `a -> d`.**

Therefore I think I need **something like the transitive reduction but for all the levels.**

Is there any algorithm to clean my graphs this way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there is an edge `a -> b` and another path `a -> x -> y -> ... -> z -> b`, then the edge `a -> b` should be removed. Is this what you want?

Comment: This actually IS what transitive reduction does - it DOES remove redundant edges for all levels.

Comment: Yup, the name is topological sorting

Comment: I think that @WhatsUp is right! However, I've seen a lot of pseudocode related with Transitive Reduction that only reduces the first level of dependencies. Finally I'm using networkx which is quite good!

Answer (score 0):

I has implemented transitive reduction for all levels.
If any one find for this. It here

```html
void process() {

    // Build a side-graph edge2 ( init by clone mainGraph edge ). if a > b > c and a > c  = false. make a > c true
    // the side-graph make the multi level problem same as the first level problem
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    if (edge2[i][k] && edge2[k][j] && !edge2[i][j]) {
                        edge2[i][j] = true;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    // Check transitive at edge2 ( subGraph )
    // update transitive at edge ( mainGraph )
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if (edge[i][j]) {

                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    if (edge2[i][k] && edge2[k][j]) {
                        if (edge[i][j]) {
                            reduceNumber++;
                        }

                        edge[i][j] = false;

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```